# Is there a pejorative word for an ethnic appeal?

Tags: offensive-language, pejorative-language, ethnonyms

When ultra-conservative Jesse Helms ran against Congressman [Nick Galifianakis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Galifianakis) in 1972, he is considered to have gained ground with the slogan, "Jesse Helms: He's One of Us," presumably referring to his opponent's Greek background. If his opponent were black, the slogan would be considered racist. What's the corresponding word for this situation? *[Ethnicist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnicism)* seems too mild but may be best.

Comment: "Ethnicist" is a neologism itself, coined in the context of minority ethnic groups either attempting to raise their status within a "host" nation, or to acquire/retain territory where they can autonomously manage their own affairs. Your Jesse Helms has nothing in common with those people. The "Us" he aligns himself with is the *Goood Ole US of A*. In the UK we might say he aspires to appeal to [Middle England](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=middle+england&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=D3RETvjKM8mxhQfti4mfBg&ved=0CBsQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2ca4d88640674171&biw=1376&bih=888)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct term is still *racist*. The definition of *[race](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/race--2?region=us&rskey=NlYJpt&result=2)* includes ethnicity:

> - each of the major divisions of humankind, having distinct physical characteristics
> - a group of people sharing the same culture, history, language, etc.; an ethnic group